# Should I give a salesman who is selling to me access to my analytics?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, search-engines, analytics

An SEO sales web guy is asking for access to my Google Analytics so that he can "report back to me" with how he can help.  I know it is just a sales tactic, etc., but is there any harm in doing this?

Should I not? What should I say if you think I should tell him no?

Comment: Yeah. Dont' do this! If he is serious, let him figure it out. He should be able to see enough without your GA account to be effective. If he asks Why not?, then tell him that you do not make it ah habit of giving out your username and password to strangers. If he wants you to make him an account, just laugh. That should do the trick. If he keeps babbling on, then just leave or hang up. He is seeking an advantage over you. He should be proving himself and not trying to baffle you with bull****.

Comment: Another quick point. Some of these companies take your data and use it against you. They do this by boosting your competitions position who may already be a customer. Do not do this at the sales point. You are giving away the store. Make them work for your business. The salesman should be impressing the ever-living snot out of you just walking in the door. Make them sweat a bit. It is fun. I promise. Cheers!!

Comment: No prob: non-disclosure agreement. But if you mean that would be just a sell tactic, i guess you dont need any seo guy because of general mistrust

Comment: NDAs for small companies are mostly a joke, they take a ton of legal resources/money to prove, and have questionable outcomes eg. The salesman is fired...meanwhile the other company he leaked info for is now doing awesome. So, even if you win, you've still basically lost.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be suspicious just yet. Just ask them what data they want, and use Google Analytic's [export feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1038573?hl=en) to send them any specific reports.

Marketers & consultants need as much as information as possible about their client's customer and business in order to come up with a relevant plan & strategy.

And once you both agree on a contract, NDA, or whatever. I would give them direct access. Let the guy dig deeper into the data and allow him to give you regular updates about your site's performance.

**But don't give him your login & password! That's a big NO!** If he ask, just end it.

GA has a [user management feature](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009702?hl=en) to give other people full or limited access to your analytics. So this sort of request is very common.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great first answer.   You provide counterpoint to the other answers and back up what you have to say with references and documentation.

Comment: A good SEO should be able to make a sound initial assessment on the website itself. This should be the first step. Once this has been done satisfactorily THEN begin providing the indepth understanding of the business. Analytics data alone is not 'undertstanding a business'.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that it can go.

1. Don't give him anything -> that's what I'll do.
2. Give him access, but...

Don't do this without any signed paper. 
If it's possible, sign some kind of confidential contract with him to be sure that he is not going to use this against you.

Comment: Just be aware: if the salesman's company is not afraid of you suing them, an NDA may not be worth much.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: **NO**. Do not give anyone access who you're not actually paying to do something clearly set out.

As the answers already say above. If he IS any good, he should be able to give you an assessment based on what's in the public domain (your website and SERPs results).

What to say to him? I would just tell it how it is: "It's privileged, private, confidential information so not given out and you should be able to give me a view without it, so send me a report and I'll consider it". If he carrys on: "If you're worth the money you should be able to give me a report based on what's in the public domain. Without it, I'm not even entering into discussion about it, good-day and goodbye"

However... he has, so far, failed to gain your trust... so I wouldn't give it serious consideration. Though I'm betting you'll never see a report to give consideration to.

---

It's nothing to do with 'non-disclosure'. It's to do with making it easy for him to fabricate stories and bamboozle you using your own data.

Comment: "already don't trust him" - that's an odd disqualifier. Who would trust a salesman whom you don't know well? You *start with* not trusting.

Comment: I agree Tim, however lala has had a conversation with the party concerned and doesn't appear to have shifted from 'not trusting' at all. One would expect early conversations to inject at least some trust surely? Perhaps I'm reading too much between the lines. (I would disagree that everyone starts with not trusting btw. Some folks trust too much, hence their life savings disappear).

Comment: I'm just thinking "has so far failed to gain your trust" might be better than "already don't trust." (That is my +1 by the way, just trying to smooth out the rough edges here.)

Comment: Edited Tim. I'm appreciating your feedback. Am all for smooth edges and the debates that achieve them. Helps us all improve our answers, so all good.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an agency like a digital marketing agency then they will require access to your GA account. This is a formal agency however with contracts, SLA's and NDAs so if that's the sort of guy and this isn't under the table then give it to him.

However if it's not a digital agency and it's all abit 'under the table' then don't. You've not really given enough information re: what kind of guy this is and where he's from